# How to change colour in Object Tracking

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, simulink, matlab-cvst, video-tracking

this is a Matlab example code from Arindam Bose to track red objects.
I have changed this code a little to track objects from a video stream.
Originally it was to track red objects from a camera.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28757-tracking-red-color-objects-using-matlab

However I also want to track objects with other colours like green, black, white, etc, too. I was studying the code but can not really see where to change this colour information.

Maybe it is this line fo code which is responsible for changing colour?

```
diffFrame = imsubtract(rgbFrame(:,:,1), rgb2gray(rgbFrame)); % Get red component of the image
```

or

I have also changed the treshold, but no success:

```
redThresh = 0.15; % Threshold for red detection
```

But no idea how to change oject colour to green or some other colour.

Thanks for any suggestion.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Program Name : Red Object Detection and Tracking
% Author : Arindam Bose
% Version : 1.05
% Description : How to detect and track red objects in Live Video
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Initialization
redThresh = 0.15; % Threshold for red detection

%vidDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_640x480', ... % Acquire input video stream
%'ROI', [1 1 640 480], ...
%'ReturnedColorSpace', 'rgb');

vidInfo = VideoReader('MyVideo.avi');
videoResult = VideoWriter('C:\MyProject\Y_Videos\ResultVideo.avi');  % Finales Video mit Koordinaten der roten Blobs 
open(videoResult); % Öffne finales Video 

% vidInfo = readframe(video); % Acquire input video property

hblob = vision.BlobAnalysis('AreaOutputPort', false, ... % Set blob analysis handling
'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
'BoundingBoxOutputPort', true', ...
'MinimumBlobArea', 10, ...
'MaximumBlobArea', 950, ...
'MaximumCount', 30);
hshapeinsRedBox = vision.ShapeInserter('BorderColor', 'Custom', ... % Set Red box handling
'CustomBorderColor', [255 255 255], ...
'Fill', true, ...
'FillColor', 'Custom', ...
'CustomFillColor', [0 0 0], ...
'Opacity', 0.3);
htextins = vision.TextInserter('Text', 'Red Objects: %2d', ... % Set text for number of blobs
'Location', [7 2], ...
'Color', [255 255 255], ... // red color
'FontSize', 14);
htextinsCent = vision.TextInserter('Text', '+ X:%4d, Y:%4d', ... % set text for centroid
'LocationSource', 'Input port', ...
'Color', [255 255 255], ... // white color
'FontSize', 14);

hVideoIn = vision.VideoPlayer('Name', 'Final Video', ... % Output video player
'Position', [100 100 610 500]);
nFrame = 0; % Frame number initialization
%% Processing Loop
while(nFrame < 500)
rgbFrame = readFrame(vidInfo);
%rgbFrame = step(vidDevice); % Acquire single frame
%rgbFrame = flip(rgbFrame,2); % obtain the mirror image for displaying
diffFrame = imsubtract(rgbFrame(:,:,1), rgb2gray(rgbFrame)); % Get red component of the image
diffFrame = medfilt2(diffFrame, [3 3]); % Filter out the noise by using median filter
binFrame = im2bw(diffFrame, redThresh); % Convert the image into binary image with the red objects as white
[centroid, bbox] = step(hblob, binFrame); % Get the centroids and bounding boxes of the blobs
centroid = uint16(centroid); % Convert the centroids into Integer for further steps
rgbFrame(1:20,1:165,:) = 100; % put a black region on the output stream
vidIn = step(hshapeinsRedBox, rgbFrame, bbox); % Instert the red box

for object = 1:1:length(bbox(:,1)) % Write the corresponding centroids
centX = centroid(object,1); 
centY = centroid(object,2);
vidIn = step(htextinsCent, vidIn, [centX centY], [centX-6 centY-9]);
end
vidIn = step(htextins, vidIn, uint8(length(bbox(:,1)))); % Count the number of blobs
step(hVideoIn, vidIn); % Output video stream

writeVideo(videoResult,vidIn)

nFrame = nFrame+1;
end

%% Clearing Memory
release(hVideoIn); % Release all memory and buffer used
%% release(vidDevice);
%%clear all;
close(videoResult);

clc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. Colour images are `n x m x 3` matrices, so `img(:,:,1)` is the red channel, `img(:,:,2)` the green one, and `img(:,:,3)` the blue one.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a possibility to get also white object, like a white ball?

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem, you just have to decompose your desired colour into RGB, and then combine the RGB channels accordingly. In the special case of *white* I think `rgb2gray` would be sufficient.